# Use smoother with stat_summary means and value-dependent dot size

Tags: r, mean, smoothing

I want to map the activity of soil organisms in regard of soil depth for different sites.
I restructured my data from wide to long format and created a new data frame with only the three necessary variables (Group.1 = soil depth, Group.2 = site name, x = mean of soil organism activity).
I plotted the data as follows:

```
heatmap_plot <- ggplot(baits.activity.means, aes(x= Group.2, y=Group.1, size = x, 
colour=Group.2))
heatmap_plot + stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point")  +
labs(title = "Soil Biological Activity Distribution", 
   x = "Site", y = "Soil Depth") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold")) +
scale_fill_discrete(name="Site")
```

This leaves me with:

[image: Soil biological activity distribution]

Now I struggle with two things:

1. First, I'd like the y axis to show the soil depth in increasing order, so from -8 cm to -0.5 cm (-8 cm being the lowest soil "layer")
2. EDIT 1: is there a simple way by which I could change the size for all points together by the same factor?

EDIT 2: I came up with yet another way to illustrate my data, but am lost by how to start. Below a rough sketch:

[image: Plot sketch]

The x axis shows the soil depth. For each soil depth level, I'd like to show the average activity value by a bar (the higher the bar, the higher the average). Ideally, I'd like to add a smoother showing the course of the means along the soil depth (x axis).
Or (but likely a bit more complicated) to illustrate bars with high values e.g. in green color, bars with low values in red color - i.e. use a color gradient to fill the bars, to make it easier to spot soil depths with higher average activity.

The original long format data has over 5400 observations, so I just provide the smaller data frame (baits.activity.means) with means gathered with aggregate():

```
structure(list(Group.1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L), .Label = c("-0.5", 
"-1", "-1.5", "-2", "-2.5", "-3", "-3.5", "-4", "-4.5", "-5", 
"-5.5", "-6", "-6.5", "-7", "-7.5", "-8"), class = "factor"), 
    Group.2 = c("TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", 
    "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", "TNH", 
    "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", 
    "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TNM", "TSH", "TSH", 
    "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", 
    "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", "TSH", "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", 
    "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", 
    "TSM", "TSM", "TSM", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", 
    "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", "VNH", 
    "VNH", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", 
    "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VNM", "VSH", 
    "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", 
    "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSH", "VSM", "VSM", "VSM", 
    "VSM", "VSM", "VSM", "VSM", "VSM", "VSM", "VSM", "VSM", "VSM", 
    "VSM", "VSM", "VSM", "VSM"), x = c(0.230357142857143, 0.351785714285714, 
    0.282142857142857, 0.189285714285714, 0.169642857142857, 
    0.139285714285714, 0.0821428571428571, 0.0410714285714286, 
    0.0553571428571429, 0.0178571428571429, 0.0303571428571429, 
    0.0303571428571429, 0.0571428571428571, 0.0642857142857143, 
    0.0160714285714286, 0.0803571428571429, 0.61, 0.602222222222222, 
    0.414444444444444, 0.488888888888889, 0.337777777777778, 
    0.304444444444444, 0.366666666666667, 0.313333333333333, 
    0.348888888888889, 0.307777777777778, 0.254444444444444, 
    0.276666666666667, 0.124444444444444, 0.235555555555556, 
    0.165555555555556, 0.255555555555556, 0.664634146341463, 
    0.585365853658537, 0.535365853658537, 0.413414634146341, 
    0.395121951219512, 0.209756097560976, 0.252439024390244, 
    0.197560975609756, 0.170731707317073, 0.024390243902439, 
    0, 0.0146341463414634, 0, 0.0365853658536585, 0.0182926829268293, 
    0, 0.11, 0.143333333333333, 0.0944444444444444, 0.15, 0.127777777777778, 
    0.0666666666666667, 0.0744444444444444, 0.0555555555555556, 
    0.0755555555555556, 0.00555555555555556, 0.03, 0.05, 0.0511111111111111, 
    0.0611111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0888888888888889, 
    0.5, 0.346666666666667, 0.19, 0.191111111111111, 0.147777777777778, 
    0.1, 0.0988888888888889, 0.0866666666666667, 0.08, 0.0344444444444444, 
    0.0522222222222222, 0.0344444444444444, 0.0633333333333333, 
    0.0377777777777778, 0.0588888888888889, 0.0577777777777778, 
    0.911111111111111, 0.851111111111111, 0.75, 0.628888888888889, 
    0.644444444444444, 0.536666666666667, 0.541111111111111, 
    0.491111111111111, 0.425555555555556, 0.411111111111111, 
    0.29, 0.224444444444444, 0.232222222222222, 0.263333333333333, 
    0.13, 0.181111111111111, 0.377777777777778, 0.257777777777778, 
    0.198888888888889, 0.151111111111111, 0.147777777777778, 
    0.13, 0.168888888888889, 0.108888888888889, 0.106666666666667, 
    0.147777777777778, 0.126666666666667, 0.152222222222222, 
    0.125555555555556, 0.12, 0.101111111111111, 0.11, 0.262222222222222, 
    0.296666666666667, 0.241111111111111, 0.283333333333333, 
    0.198888888888889, 0.168888888888889, 0.15, 0.122222222222222, 
    0.11, 0.0877777777777778, 0.11, 0.111111111111111, 0.127777777777778, 
    0.127777777777778, 0.154444444444444, 0.15)), row.names = c(NA, 
-128L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: On second thoughts, a violin plot might be what you're looking for. It can show you the distribution of values for each site. You can use it in ggplot by adding  `geom_violin()`. Could be a decent place to start.

This should work to reverse the y axis for point 1 (see the last line). But I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for point 2.

```
heatmap_plot <- ggplot(baits.activity.means, aes(x= Group.2, y=Group.1, size = x, 
colour=Group.2))
heatmap_plot + stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point")  +
labs(title = "Soil Biological Activity Distribution", 
   x = "Site", y = "Soil Depth") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold")) +
scale_fill_discrete(name="Site") + 
scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(baits.activity.means$`Group.1`)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix regarding the y axis, I thought there must be a simple solution but just did not find something that worked for me. And the hint about trying a violin plot sounds very promising, I'll try and see whether I'll get it to work. I noticed that a geom_smooth or similar does not really make sense in this context, so sorry for the confusion!

Comment: After some more thoughts, I don't quite see how to implement this for my data & the visualisation purpose. I came up with another way how I could plot the data following my original intention. I'll add a sketch in the original question